# Can I delete /var/log/btmp and /var/log/auth.log files?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, centos7

I am using a CentOS server with password protected SSH connection.

Recently my server ran out of memory, I looked at the largest files and saw this

```
du -a /var/log | sort -n -r | head -n 10
16511636        /var/log
11348496        /var/log/upstart
11348372        /var/log/upstart/docker.log
3370656 /var/log/btmp
1739268 /var/log/auth.log
41688   /var/log/mail.log
10256   /var/log/syslog
512     /var/log/wtmp
244     /var/log/dpkg.log
172     /var/log/apt
```

Look at `/var/log/btmp` (over 3GB) and `/var/log/auth.log` (over 1.7GB).

I have a thousands of users daily on that website/server.

Can I delete those files? is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

You are better off just slicking them with something like

```
cat /dev/null > /var/log/btmp
cat /dev/null > /var/log/auth.log
```

Answer (score 0):

`btmp` logs failed attempts into your system. In theory this could mean someone is trying to brute force passwords. You can empty this file but should not remove it since software could crash when it expects the file to be there. To empty it from command line:

```
sudo > /var/log/btmp
```

If it gets filled quickly you really should investigate why.